# Unzip all files into directories with the same name

Tags: files, directory, zip

Ubuntu 16.04

I have a directory with `zip` files like this:

```
directory
|
|---zip1.zip
|---zip2.zip
|
...
|---zip_very_large_number.zip
```

Now, I have another directory `/home/usrname/anotherdir`. Is there a way to unzip all the files into the `/home/usrname/anotherdir` in the following way:

```
/home/usrname/anotherdir
|---zip1(directory)
|    |---_FILES_FROM_zip1.zip
|
|---zip2(directory)
|    |---_FILES_FROM_zip2.zip
|
|---zip3(directory)
|    |---_FILES_FROM_zip3.zip
|
...
|
|---zip_very_large_number(directory)
     |---_FILES_FROM_zip_very_large_number.zip
```

Is there a concise way to do this with `unzip`? I could write a shell-script but it doesn't look pretty well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a short way to do this with `unzip`, since it only accepts one zipfile for decompression at a time. Consider some sort of shell loop like:

```
for d in *.zip
do
  dir=/home/usrname/anotherdir/zip${d%%.zip}
  unzip -d "$dir" "$d"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one liner that works for any zips in the current directory

```bsh
for z in *.zip; do unzip "$z" -d "${z%".zip"}"; done
```

You can add it to your `.bashrc`

```bsh
alias unzip_all='for z in *.zip; do unzip "$z" -d "${z%".zip"}"; done'
```

Inspiration taken from:

`Method #2: Unzipping Multiple Files from Linux Command Line Using Shell For Loop (Long Version)` in https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-unzipping-many-zip-files/